# Rails 3 - Asset Pipeline -- What does it mean to me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am struggling to find any real documentation on the new Rails 3 asset pipeline. I know there is a video, but I do not wish to watch an hour video in this format. I watched about 10 minutes and gained no knowledge.

So, what do I need to know about Rails 3 asset pipelines? What does this mean to my previous projects, and what does it mean to my future projects?

Comment: Can you please share the link to this video?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you will now be able to write css and javascript in separate files using `sass` and `coffeescript` if you want and they will be compiled into one single file in the end.

If you have like, 4 css files on your `assets/stylesheets` they will be concatenated and compressed and delivered on production with a single application.css file.

Same thing applies to javascript files.

More info in http://getsprockets.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can get some good documentation here on rails guides here

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

It's a great way to serve fast assets for your application. Sprockets is playing a major role in it.